# Is there anyway to center text within a TextField horizontally and vertically?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

In Android compose is there anyway to center text within a TextField?

```
    TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = setText,
    maxLines = 2,
    modifier = modifier
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
        .background(Color(0xffe2ebf0))
        .border(BorderStroke(5.dp, color = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary), shape = RoundedCornerShape(1.dp)),
    textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.h3,
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = { submit() })

)
```

[image: Cannot post images yet... So here is a link!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `textAlign = TextAlign.Center` in the `TextStyle`.

Something like:

```
TextField(
    //...your code
    textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.h3.copy(textAlign = TextAlign.Center),
)
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers. That isn't necessarily intuitive compared to Compose solutions to other UI attributes.

Comment: Certainly compose has never heard of the Law of Demeter ...

Comment: This would only center the text horizontally tho.